# Want to add Search Edit box . Which can search the employee name from the Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

In my Employee directory project . I am trying to add the search edit box for the list view from where we search the Employee from his name.
I am using following code for showing the employee list in a list view from the database .

```
    public class Contacts_list_sceen_2 extends Activity {
    protected ListView lv1; 
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;// cursor to query the database
protected ListAdapter adapter;
protected Button back_button;
protected Button about_button;
int position = 0;
TextView tm;
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
    this.setTitle("contactlistscreen2");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
final   int id = intent.getIntExtra("team_id", 1);


    DataStorage storage = DataStorage.getDataStorageHandle(this,
            Metidirectory.db_path);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    lv1.setAdapter(new CustomCursorAdaptor(this, storage.getEmpDetail(id)));
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            cursor cursor = (Cursor)
                            parent.getItemAtPosition(position);



            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("Data", new EmployeeBean(cursor));
            i.setClassName("com.guru.vinay",
            "com.guru.vinay.Database_display_activity");

            startActivity(i) ;
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use addTextChangeListener() for the EditText which you want to search. You can use this post to implement this functionality. http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html